# Is it considered bad practice to use both Asymptote and TikZ in the same document?

Tags: tikz-pgf, best-practices, asymptote

I'm something of a beginner in both Asymptote and PGF/TikZ, but I'm a bit better at Asymptote, and so I generally find Asymptote easier to use. However, I find Bezier curves a bit easier to control with TikZ.

Of course, the obvious (and best) solution is to just get better at one/both of them. I'm not really asking for recommendations for either Asymptote or TikZ (although they're always welcome!).

What I was really wondering was this: In general, is it considered bad practice to use both Asymptote *and* TikZ in the same document? Or is it acceptable? For example, I can imagine that even for an advanced user of both, there are relative strengths to each, which might make it desirable to use both languages.

Comment: Did you mean mixing both TikZ and Aysmptote in a single canvas? If they are different canvas, I don't think it is bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not a bad practice, even if both look different. Some of my classmates use TikZ and Asymptote and their codes are pretty easy to read and understand.

As you say, I recommend to improve in just one to have an homogeneous code.

Answer (score 3):

> [E]ven for an advanced user of both, there are relative strengths to each, which might make it desirable to use both languages.

This is absolutely correct. Asymptote is king for 3d images and programming, but Ti*k*Z is better for text-based diagrams and of the two is the only one that can draw things (e.g. arrows) that directly interact with content outside the image. And for certain tasks that are theoretically within the purview of both, one may happen to have a library suited for that particular task.